# 2D openGL drawing lines that don't exactly fit pixel raster

Tags: c, opengl, rendering, 2d, antialiasing

I'm drawing something similar to a LED VU meter in OpenGL. Result should be like on vertical bar of this:

[image: Animated vumeters]

Unfortunately, my drawing space is restricted, and I have to fit exactly 18 bars on it. That yields a spacing between bars of 3.6 pixels.

When drawn, this causes visible differences in the gaps between lines, because the gaps are either 2 or 1 pixel wide. I'm looking for a solution to use subpixel rendering and than "fake" the lines by some kind of anti-aliasing, so that all gaps appear of the same width.

This is my code so far

```
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);
for (int i = 0; i < 18; ++i) {
            float bBottom = barBottom + i*3.6f;
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glLineWidth(2);
            glVertex2f(bRight,bBottom);
            glVertex2f(bLeft,bBottom);
            glEnd();
}
glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
```

Unfortunately, turning on line smoothing showed no visible effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: Round the pixel values to integers.

Comment: `GL_LINE_SMOOTH` is not supported by all implementations.  And I agree with @Matt Ball that you should round the lines to integral pixels, and draw a boundary line or just leave a gap at the top (of about 10px in this case).

Answer (score 4):

Two ideas:

1. Draw all the bars to a large off screen texture such that the gaps and widths are all equal and then use bilinear filtering to blit the result to the required screen position and size.
2. Get an artist to draw all the fully lit bars so that the look good, then draw black rectangles with an alpha channel from the top of each bar downwards to darken the required parts of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Use multisampling ([Multisampling specs](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/wgl_multisample.txt)).

Additionally, I would use quads (and not lines) for rendering those blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't enable antialiasing for your OpenGl context, you can emulate it - it's easy with such simple graphics. When you need to draw rectangle 10.6 pixels high, draw it 10 pixels with its color and then single pixel line of intermediate color (0.6 of rectangle color and 0.4 of background color).

Comment: Depending on the subpixel alignment of the monitor this will work in only one direction, most probable the vertical. OpenGL is not really usefull for this kind of things, i.e. high quality vector graphics. It's first and foremost thought to push triangles of 3D tesselated object on the screen.

Comment: Never heard about "subpixel alignment of the monitor", what is it?

Comment: The layout of individual red/green/blue dots on the LCD - they're not in the same place. It's used primarily in high-quality font antialiasing (ClearType etc).

Comment: I don't see why care for subpixel dots for antialiasing. You don't have that information anyway.

Comment: This is why subpixel alignment matters: http://www.antigrain.com/research/font_rasterization/index.html#FONT_RASTERIZATION also you can retrieve the monitors subpixel alignment from its EDID

Comment: @alxx Don't be so narrowminded. This is not just about text. This is about placing geometroy on fractional pixel positions. It applies to all forms of geometry.